# Renaming all files ending with .c present in recursive directory

Tags: shell, scripting

I need shell script which prepends some string into the file-name (.c files)  present in a directory and sub-directory.

For Example: If `lokesh` is parent directory and inside it `lokesh1` and `lokesh2` is the subdirectory and inside `lokesh1` (`1.c` , `2.c` ...) and inside `lokesh2`(`a.c` , `b.c` ...). Hence after running the script I want to change it to (`x_1.c`, `x_2.c` ... ) and `(x_a.c,` `x_b.c` ...).

Comment: Larry Wall's `rename` could be useful. (never tried it recursive, but you could combine with `find`)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I tend to stay away from `rename`, especially in answers here, as there are at least two different utilities with that name. It would probably do the job though.

Comment: Yes I should have been clearer, **Larry Wall's version** (of `rename`) not any other one. There are at least two.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Ah, I'm getting older and my hearing is failing me.  ;-)

Comment: This all i have tried its not working please suggest some different script.

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE:** When writing the below, I was using OpenBSD `find` with which `-execdir utility {} ';'` will replace `{}` with the basename of the found files.  With GNU `find`, the `{}` will also be the basename of the found file, but it will additionally be prepended by `./`, which renders the first `find` command below useless.  For users of GNU `find` (most people on Linux, for example), scroll down to the other variations of the solution.

---

You want to find all `.c` files in or beneath the `lokesh` directory and prepend their names with `x_`.

```
find lokesh -type f -name '*.c' -execdir echo mv {} x_{} ';'
```

The `-type f` and `-name '*.c'` expressions will find all the relevant files while `-execdir mv {} x_{} ';'` will rename the found files.

The `-execdir` expression is not standard, but most implementations of `find` supports it.  It differs from `-exec` in that the given utility is executed with the parent directory of the found pathname as the working directory.  The `{}` in the command line will therefore be the basename of the files that we want to rename (not the complete pathname as with `-exec`).

Run this once, and then remove the `echo` when you have seen that it does the correct thing.  The `echo` will prevent the `mv` from actually renaming the files.

---

On systems which doesn't support `-execdir` (or which doesn't do `-execdir` like OpenBSD does):

```
find lokesh -type f -name '*.c' \
    -exec sh -c 'for name do echo mv "$name" "${name%/*}/x_${name##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

or, shorter but ever so slightly less efficient,

```
find lokesh -type f -name '*.c' \
    -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%/*}/x_${1##*/}"' sh {} ';'
```

Both of these variation employ a short shell script that basically does the same thing in the end:

```
mv "$name" "${name%/*}/x_${name##*/}"
```

This moves the file given its full pathname in `$name` to a new name that is prefixed by `x_` in the same directory.  The `${name%/*}` parameter substitution is equivalent to `$( dirname "$name" )` and will give parent directory of the pathname, while `${name##*/}` is equivalent to `$( basename "$name" )` which will give the basename (the filename component) of the pathname.

Comment: Thanks for you script but its not working please suggest some different script.

Comment: @LokeshKumar Ah, I see now. There's a typo in my solution (which I did not have while testing). Fixed now. I was missing `-c` after `sh` in the `find` commands.

Comment: yes this script worked for me:      find . -type f -name '*.c' \
    -exec sh -c ' mv "$1" "${1%/*}/x_${1##*/}"' sh {} ';'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but kindly could you please explain the whole part of script.    find . -type f -name '*.c' \
                -exec sh -c ' mv "$1" "${1%/*}/x_${1##*/}"' sh {} ';'

Comment: @LokeshKumar The `mv` part is already explained in the answer. The `-exec` makes `find` call `sh -c` which executes the `mv`. This happens for the files that match `*.c`. Which part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%/*}/x_${1##*/}"' sh {} ';'   what is  sh -c and what $1" "${1%/*}/x_${1##*/}"' sh {} ';' does it mean?

Comment: @LokeshKumar `$1` is the parameter (the path to a C file) passed to the script that `sh -c` executes. `${1%/*}` will be the directory where the file is located. `x_${1##*/}` is the new name of the file (`${1##*/}` will be the old filename).

Comment: yeah got it . Thanks a lot. In place of 1 we can write anything or only 1 is applicable.?

Comment: @LokeshKumar You could use `-exec sh -c 'name="$1"; mv "$name" "${name%/*}/x_${name##*/}"' sh {} ';'` or, if you want to be very verbose, `-exec -exec sh -c 'name="$1"; mv "$name" "$(dirname "$name")/x_$(basename "$name")"' sh {} ';'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl rename, if available. By Perl rename, I mean either prename or file-rename, and not rename.ul which might be what `rename` points to your system, and which will definitely error out if you try to use it with the code arguments I have suggested below...

On my system (Ubuntu 17.10 - I installed the `rename` package to get Perl rename):

```
$ readlink -e $(type -P rename)
/usr/bin/file-rename
```

This is the only environment in which I have tested this answer!

If you have only two directory levels as in your example, you could run from the `lokesh` directory something like this:

```
rename -n 's|/|/x_|' */*.c
```

Always run first with the `-n` flag, which shows what change will be attempted if you run the same code without `-n`. If you are seeing the right result, remove `-n`.

If you have a complex directory structure, you can use recursive globbing if available. In Bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then try `rename`:

```
rename -n 's|(.*)/|$1/x_|' ./**/*.c
```

This captures everything before the last path element `(.*)/` and reproduces it with the backreference `$1`.

Otherwise (if you can't use recursive globbing), use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec rename -n 's|(.*)/|$1/x_|' {} +
```

Although it will be slower if the files are in many directories, you can also use `-execdir` which allows a simpler regex (I found a noticeable speed difference between `-exec` (less than a second) and `-execdir` (3-4 seconds) with ~1113 `.c` files in ~175 directories):

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -execdir rename -n 's|/|/x_|' {} +
```

The `-n` gives confusing-looking results with `-execdir` but if the base names look right, we are ok.

However, thanks to a [comment by Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435987/renaming-all-files-ending-with-c-present-in-recursive-directory/436019?noredirect=1#comment787654_436019), I realise this depends on having GNU `find` where all the `-execdir` arguments start with `./`, and not the OpenBSD version where they do not. If the filename has no path prefix at all, then I would guess you could use this version:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -execdir rename -n -- 's|^|x_|' {} +
```

but I can't test that as I don't have OpenBSD `find`.

However, **[Eliah Kagan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11938/eliah-kagan) very helpfully [came up with this much better regex](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43863153#43863153)** that works regardless of the implementation of `find` you are using and whether you use `-exec` or `-execdir`, and works with recursive globbing too:

```
rename -n 's|[^/]+$|x_$&|'
```

This matches at least 1 character(s) that are not `/` at the end (`$`) of the path, and then reproduces the whole match (`$&`) after the added `x_`. This command *should* work anywhere `find` and Perl rename are available:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec rename -n 's|[^/]+$|x_$&|' {} +
```

Comment: Is the regular expression correct for the `-execdir` variation? The arguments will not have a `/` in them... Can't test here ATM, sorry.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, it works because the arguments all start with `./`. But perhaps there is a more efficient way to prepend... I am not very good at finding the nicest possible regex! [here's the result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TgzQwHT96J/)

Comment: Oh, they _do_ start with `./` if I use GNU `find`, but not if I use my native OpenBSD `find`! That's awkward since it probably means my own answer is wrong for GNU `find`...

Comment: oooh that's good to know! I better make a note O.O. (also hmm... looking at my pastie, I see the function I wrote to make `pastebinit` include the command run is capturing that command after quote removal, which is probably not fixable...)

Comment: Thanks for your time, i tried this script but its not working. Please suggest some different script.

Comment: Simpler `rename`: just append `x_` at the end of the directory part, and that directory part is matched by `.*/` (due to greedy match), which gives: `rename 's|.*/|$&x_|'`